# Editing questions and answers for typos and grammer

Tags: discussion

My native language is not English, but sometimes there are Q&A's that are screaming for editing.

I know that on SF and SU, there are requests to NOT edit Q&A for single or few spelling errors.

An example is this Q: [How can I create a Chatter Free License user in a test class?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/how-do-i-create-an-user-with-a-chatter-free-license-in-test-class) - Q's subject is in need of a fix, I guess during the Beta we can do these little fixes, or not? what say you?

p.s.: for that example, my new subject would be:

> How can I create a Chatter Free License user in a test class?

Answer (score 4):

I would say: style-only edits should be avoided, but obvious grammar and typos (such as the title of this question :) are fair game. I don't see how anyone can argue with correcting misspellings or incorrect grammar; plus fixing those things improves the content on the site.

Answer (score 3):

I just had a few moments where I was editing a question because of poor code documentation or an incomplete title. Specifically:

- Poor Grammar: [Can we insert Attachments on a Case using Force.com Sites?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9193/can-we-insert-attachments-on-a-case-using-force-com-sites)
- Poor tags/Improper Title: [Rerender a pageBlock if a value is entered in an inputField?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9192/rerender-a-pageblock-if-a-value-is-entered-in-an-inputfield)

I felt like it was alright for me to edit these questions with the following:

- The first question had incorrectly included code and I went in to edit the question to properly display the code. During that process I also:

  - Edited poor grammar (such as proper punctuation)
  - Capitalized the word I
  - Added a space between a period and the first letter of the next sentence
- The second question had the title as "rerender a pageblock". After reading the question, I realized that the title didn't accurately represent the question. The question also had some incorrect tags. During that process I also:

  - Edited a reference to code later in the question to make it stand out more
  - Edited some capitalization to make it easier to read

I would say both of those are good candidates for editing. We have to remember that this site's main goal is to be a Q/A site but it also needs to be user friendly. Poorly written questions that eventually get repeated or become difficult to find via search engine are bad for the site. Editing a question to fix grammar or spelling mistakes is something that just makes the entire site look more professional and it makes it clearer for new users to find information.

Answer (score 2):

My personal approach is to fix bad grammar and typos where I can just to maintain a high standard across the site. That said, if something has been obviously written by a non-native english speaker I don't like to reword their sentences entirely, in which case I fix the worst parts and let the rest slide, so they can at least see what the major mistakes were.

Whenever I see someone doing strings of periods ......... however are ALWAYS fair game.

Typos however small should always be fixed in keywords and titles should always make sense and reflect the question, this is in our interest in terms of making the site easy to search!

Answer (score 1):

I feel that editing titles and questions for clarity and reformatting code/hyperlinks is always a good thing.  Any time we make it easier for people to understand the content of the site, we all benefit.  If someone is having a hard time describing their problem, and you figure it out from reading comments on the question, it makes sense to update the title and/or question to include that information.

I think the FAQ guideline is about making minor edits to content.  There's no need to edit an answer just because someone wrote *your* instead of *you're*, but if you're already correcting other aspects of the post, I feel that it would be OK to correct that as well.